# Getting org.glassfish.hk2.extension.ServiceLocatorGenerator: Provider org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl not a subtype

Tags: java, jersey, classloader, hk2

Getting below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered
```

When I dig deep into the issue on debug mode, I realized that actual error is below one.

```
Getting org.glassfish.hk2.extension.ServiceLocatorGenerator: Provider org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl not a subtype
```

It was failing when invoking **providers.next()** in hk2-api lib

```
final ClassLoader classLoader = ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.class.getClassLoader();
      Iterator<ServiceLocatorGenerator> providers = java.util.ServiceLoader.load(ServiceLocatorGenerator.class,
              classLoader).iterator();
      while (providers.hasNext()) {
          try {
              return providers.next();
          } catch (ServiceConfigurationError sce) {
              // This can happen. See the exception javadoc for more details.
              Logger.getLogger().debug("ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl", "getGenerator", sce);
                  // We will try the next one
          }
      }
```

1. There is a interface ***ServiceLocatorGenerator*** present in kh2-api lib (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.6.1). Error says that implementation ***ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl*** present in hk2-locater lib (org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.6.1) is not subtype even though it is a subtype.
2. Understood that an implementation class (concrete class) cannot be a subtype of interface if they are not loader by same class loader. Assuming this was the one causing the issue.

Can someone help how to fix this issue in gralde? My env is not OSGi based.

Comment: This sounds like a classloading issue.  Are you using different classloaders?

Comment: @jwells131313 I'm not explicitly using any class loaders actually.

Comment: @jwells131313 Attached the code where it is failing. Do you think it's a class loader issue? Since provider is found when used caller's class loader and failing when calling next() method, I don't think its a class loader issue

Comment: Got the issue. There is another jersey dependency in my project that causing the issue.
 
"com.qubole.qds-sdk-java:qds-sdk-java:0.6.1:aws-http-jackson-jersey-shaded"